# how to calculate only days between two dates in postgres sql query .

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

Suppose I have given two dates, if difference is one month then it should be display as 30 days.Even months also need to convert into days
I have tried  with age( date,now()::timestamp without time zone) but it is giving months-dates-years format. ex: 10 mons 24 days 13:57:40.5265.But I need following way.
For example if two months difference is there then I need output as 60 days.

Comment: `current_date - your_timestamp_column::date`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show some code?

Comment: But the difference between the same day in February and March is 28 or 29 days? And the difference between the same day in March and April is 31 days.

Even if you extract the # of days you're not gonna get 30 days for each month to month comparison.

Comment: Note that in 9.6.1 I get days for this query:

select '2017-10-03 00:00:00'::timestamp - '2017-02-03 00:00:00'::timestamp;
 ?column? 
----------
 242 days

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't use the `age()` function for date/time arithmetic. It only [returns "symbolic" results](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) (which are good enough for human representation, but almost meaningless for date/time calculations; compared to the standard difference).

The standard [difference operator (`-`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) returns day-based results for both `date`, `timestamp` and `timestamp with time zone` (the former returns days as `int`, the latter two return day-based `interval`s):

From the day-based intervals you can extract days with the `extract()` function:

```
select current_date - '2017-01-01',
       extract(day from now()::timestamp - '2017-01-01 00:00:00'),
       extract(day from now()            - '2017-01-01 00:00:00Z');
```

http://rextester.com/RBTO71933

Comment: `age()` returns an `interval` not a "symbolic" result. Which is a data type that can be used very easily in calculations and is definitely **not** "meaningless"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name [from the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) *age(timestamp, timestamp): Subtract arguments, producing a "symbolic" result that uses years and months, rather than just days*, yes technically its type is `interval`, but given its (the function's) semantics and the general `interval` justification rules, it's not meant to be used in date/time arithmetics (maybe in some edge-cases).

Answer (score 0):

Both of those will give that result.

```
select make_interval(days => ((extract(epoch from '2016-04-10'::date) - extract(epoch from '2016-02-10'::date))/(60*60*24))::integer)::text;

select format('%1$s days', ((extract(epoch from '2016-04-10'::date) - extract(epoch from '2016-02-10'::date))/(60*60*24))::integer);
```